# Escaping SQLite INSERT Via ContentValues

Tags: android, sqlite

Does Android's ContentValues when used with `database.insert()` automatically escape content?

Example:

```
String message = "This is a sample that doesn't have a single quote";

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DBManagement.MESSAGE, message);
values.put(DBManagement.TIME, (int) (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000));
database.insert(DBManagement.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

It looks like it is automatically escaped at times but not others.

YI, I use `rawQuery` and parametrize the input to escape and protect against injection in other queries.

What is the deal?

Comment: "It looks like it is automatically escaped at times but not others." -- such as when?

Comment: Could you come up with an example for when the values are not escaped? What I know is that escaping is not necessary because prepared statements are used by SQLiteDatabase. I just checked the Jelly Bean source code and traced back all method calls from SQLiteDatabase.insert to SQLiteConnection.bindArguments. Arguments are individually passed to native code and not inserted into the SQL query.

Comment: Yes. Got the following error message: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "t": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO settings SET value='I really don't think that is neccessary', key='setting_option1'`. The line being referenced is the code `database.insert(....);` Am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: Wow... just to make sure I checked the source code again and at least Jelly Bean cleanly constructs a prepared statement, separating the SQL query from the passed data by using placeholders (?,?,...). Which Android API level do you use?

Comment: I was on 7 and just moved my code base to 13. That's when i started getting the error then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue. For some reason, I had to increase the database version in order to resolve the problem. Once done, the newer DB no longer had an issue.

Also, yes, ContentValues is supposed to escape your content.

Comment: I believe you are wrong. `ContentValues` does not automatically escape characters. I had an issue with it a little while back, and it made no sense. I thought it would work like in mysql_real_escape_string in PHP, but unfortunately it does not. It claims to bind the values to make it safer, but it indeed does not.